# Creating iOS share extension through the command line

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I know I can create an iOS 8 share extension with XCode UI (File > New > Target > Share Extension)

**What I want is to be able to do the same with a shell command, is this possible?**

---

#### Long story:

I am in the context of a Cordova application, and my xcodeproj is generated by Cordova. Currently I have all the Cordova app working with shell scripts without any manual procedure, but for share extension I have to ask the user, in the middle of a schell script, to perform manual operations in XCode to create the share extension. I'd like to remove that manual procedure.

Cordova does not support share extension declaration right now, and I've heard it would be complicated for them to do so, because xcodeproj file is modified in many places and is complicated.

Comment: I don't think it's possible

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105698/cordova-sharing-browser-url-to-my-ios-app-clipper-ios-share-extension