# iOS: Camera Roll access from Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I created a simple Cordova App (iOS) with the following basic functionality:

1. One taps a button to select a video from the Camera Roll (using the Camera plugin)
2. This video file is transferred to Amazon S3 (using the FileTransfer plugin)

This works splendidly, but I wanted to make this even more effortless by implementing a Sharing Extension. I succeeded in creating a plugin (based on [Cordova: sharing browser URL to my iOS app (Clipper ios share extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105698/cordova-sharing-browser-url-to-my-ios-app-clipper-ios-share-extension/34064913)) which allows the user to tap the 'Share with...' button in any video app and select my app.

In my app, I receive the file URL of the selected video:

```
file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1347.MOV
```

This is an URL directly to the Camera Roll. Is it possible to access (and copy) this file using the Cordova File plugin (or any other plugin)? Or do I need to adjust my Swift code to copy this file to the App Sandbox first?

Comment: Looks like the Camera plugin has the option to either grab a picture from the Camera itself, or the photo library: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/#camerapicturesourcetype--enum