# How to get cordova-plugin-intent working on IOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ios-extensions

I tried following plugin on ionic-cordova, to share an url from safari(IOS) to my custom mobile-app:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-intent

Even though trying all the "info.plist" and JS stuff, and also trying following solution: [Cordova: sharing browser URL to my iOS app (Clipper ios share extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105698/cordova-sharing-browser-url-to-my-ios-app-clipper-ios-share-extension), couldn't get a share-extension to work on IOS(cordova) (my app isnt even in the available-app-list to share on, from safari).

But as cordova-plugin-intent solution seems easier to setup, I would be really grateful to anybody confirming this is possible this way, and send some screenshot of its working cordova-installation-directories / *.plist files ?

For instance this is mine:
[ionic-cordova-IOS intent-plugin setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijiAD.png)

Comment: As the title of the plugin says: this plugin _Android only_. It will not work for iOS.

Comment: but what about the line stating "On iOS the method "window.handleOpenURL" is your friend [...]" ? It makes it pretty unclear if he finally did IOS or not :/

Comment: Well, thats simply how you can realize similar functionality on iOS, that has nothing to do with the plugin itself. You can always check by looking for the supported platforms in `plugin.xml`. In your case you can only see `<platform name="android">` which means only android is supported.